# Why the JSON is incorrect when in the database have a special charecter?

Tags: json, codeigniter, ms-access, special-characters

I have a problem with a JSON generated in CodeIgniter with REST Server connected to MS-Access database.
If in my database have only normal charecters, the JSON generated in the rest server work fine, but if in the database have a special character (example: Ø, ", etc...) the JSON generated is not valid, and only show a blank screen.
I think the code is correct, and the charset is set to UTF8 in the connection of the MS-Access database.
I use to check the JSON: POSTMAN, Firefox, and Chrome
This is my code to generate the JSON (i think the code is OK, because works fine (sometimes..)

```
    public function list_minimos_get(){

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT F_STO.ARTSTO, F_ART.DESART, F_ART.EQUART, F_STO.MINSTO, F_STO.ACTSTO
                FROM (F_STO
                      LEFT JOIN F_ART ON F_STO.ARTSTO = F_ART.CODART)
                      WHERE F_STO.ACTSTO<F_STO.MINSTO
                      AND F_STO.ARTSTO LIKE 'T%';
                 ");

        $respuesta = array(
            'error' => FALSE,
            'stock' =>  $query->result_array()
        );

        $this->response($respuesta);
}
```

I can change anything to work fine this? i think the problem is in the response, but i don't have any idea to fix it...

Edited part

---

I don't understand if i change the response to "Ø" type direct in the php code, works fine.

If I use the ISO-8859-15 i have a strange response,in this image you can see in the right side the symbol is OK (the response but the error is the same), in the upper side the symbol is not OK (the var_dump), and marked in PINK the error:

[image]

If i use Chrome with the plugin to change the charset, the var_dump works fine in charset ISO-8859-15 but the response don't work.
I change UTF-8 for ISO-8859-15 in all the project but don't work...

I don't understand anything...

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$response = array('error' => FALSE,'stock' =>  $query->result_array());

$this->output
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
        ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
        ->_display();
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dr. Strange, but i get the same (a blank screen) i check again, and change the "Ø" to "diameter" in text (in the database) work's fine, but i can't do it, i need show the same i have in the database (the Ø symbol)

Comment: hi @dr i updated the questions, have yo any idea?? I'm going crazy... thanks